# How to pass a variable value between 2 php files?

Tags: php

I'm developing a PHP site. There I'm loading an image to my home page like this.

```
img src="?php  echo"css/images/".$Vid_arr[count($Vid_arr)-5]."/front.jpg" ?" alt="Product Image 9"
```

Now I need to pass only this part `$Vid_arr[count($Vid_arr)-5]` to my `details.php` file. How can I do this?

Comment: Exactly how is details.php called? You don't show how it's called at all, so your question is unanswerable. Is it being loaded via a url? a local `include()` call? What...?

Comment: (a href="details.php" class="product" title="Product 9") just before the img src ...

Comment: And this img tag is within the `<a>`? a bare A tag is of no use whatsoever for figuring out what you want.

Comment: yes yes, the pages are connected fine. But it seems like I can't post <> tags here. That's why I replaced them with brackets () . And thanks for trying to help me .

Comment: Using backticks ( ` ) to surround small snippets of code in a comment. For full question text, indent the code with 4 spaces, or highlight the code and hit the `{}` button in the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are several ways to do it, first you can use a GET method, or simply use sessions:
`session_start();
 $_SESSION['foo'] = $Vid_arr[count($Vid_arr)-5];`

Answer (score 1):

if it's one variable, and this variable was available in one of the pervious pages. you can use `$_SESSION`. However, if it's not available from one of the previous pages. use `include_once('details.php');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `include_once('path_to_details.php');` just after the `<img>` line you have there and in the details.php script just use`$Vid_arr[count($Vid_arr)-5]` normally.

**include_once** will call the script you want. This way you can have many pieces of code separated in many files and you can merge them all into one by using the **include** and **include_once** functions.